# How to implement chunks

Tags: php, laravel, chunks

I am not very experienced and I run into problem. I can't figure out how to make this function use chunks. Tried all but get errors, I think I am misunderstanding something.

```
    $companies_has = Company::whereHas('websites', function ($q) {
        $q->where( 'updated_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMonth());
    })->get();
    $companies_doesnt_has = Company::whereDoesntHave('websites')->get();
    $companies = $companies_has->merge($companies_doesnt_has);
    foreach ($companies as $company) {
    $this->getWebsite($company); }
```

Comment: Is this the way you tried to use chunks, or are you trying to use chunk? can you explain what your question is about and the errors more clearly.

Comment: I just don't know right way to implement chunks to this function. Now it is without chunks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach ($companies->chunk(3) as $chunk)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($chunk as $product)
            <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $product->name }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```